# 1950s British comedy - daughter writes shocking novel about neighbours

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to identify a British comedy from the late 1950s-early 1960s, in which the daughter of the family secretly writes (and gets published) a scandalous book based on the lives of real-life people in her respectable neighbourhood. The title of her book was something like "Naked Suburbia". There's a scene where the girl blurts out at the dinner table that it should be the happiest day of her life (meaning that her book has been accepted for publication), and her father thinks she is referring to the fact that she set the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The film is [*Please Turn Over* (1959)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053174/) and the book referenced is *The Naked Revolt*.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Please_Turn_Over):

> In the quiet suburbs of an English town, seventeen-year-old Jo
>   Halliday lives a fairly boring life working as a hairdresser and
>   living at home, with her nagging mother, pompous father, and fitness
>   obsessed Aunt. Her father, an accountant, continually wishes that his
>   dreamy, untidy daughter could be more like his secretary Miss Jones.
>
> One morning the local newspaper reveals that she has authored a book -
>   The Naked Revolt - which is an instant bestseller. It tells the story
>   of a young girl who discovers the truth about her family and
>   neighbours, and flees to London to become a prostitute.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. At least I got half the book title right.